# TDD in Real Business Environment (C#, NO ASP.NET, SQL Server)

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, tdd, nunit

I want to keep myself as short as possible:

First: I read related posts, but they didn't help a lot.

See: [What is a quality real world example of TDD in action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612/what-is-a-quality-real-world-example-of-tdd-in-action)

Or: [How do you do TDD in a non-trivial application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211346/how-do-you-do-tdd-in-a-non-trivial-application)

Or: [TDD in ASP.NET MVC: where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717465/tdd-in-asp-net-mvc-where-to-start)

*Background*:

1. I'm not a total TDD beginner, I know the principles
2. I read Rob C Martin and MC Feathers and the like
3. TDD works fine for me in Bowling and TicTacToe Games

But I'm kind of lost when I want to to TDD in my workplace. It's not about Mocking, I kinda do know how to mock the dependecies.

*It's more:*

- WHEN do I code WHAT?
- WHERE do I begin?
- And: WHEN and HOW do I implement the "database" or "file system" code. It's cool to mock it but at integration test stage I need id as real code.

**Imagine this** (example):

- Write a program which reads a list of all customers from a database.
- Related to the customer IDs it has to search data from a csv/Excel file.
- Then the business logic does magic to it.
- At the end the results are written to the database (different table).

I never found a TDD example for an application like that.

EDIT:
How would you as a programmer would implement this example in TDD style?

*PS: I'm not talking about db-unit testing or gui unit testing.*

Comment: Someone please correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems like it would be better received over on Programmers?

Comment: I got the answers I was looking for so I do not understand why this question could be "too broad" or unclear? Sorry, I'm new member of SO, but I'm a "reader" of SO for years. I gave an example at the end, I want to know how other programmers would implement this in TDD Style -> I'll add that to the question to clear things up

Comment: "Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided By Tests" is an great book worth considering.

Comment: Thank you, looks very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start without a database entirely. Just write an interface with the most basic method to retrieve the customers

```
public interface ICustomerHandler
{
    List<Customer> GetCustomers(int customerId);
}
```

Then, using your mocking framework, mock that interface while writing a test for a method that will use and refer to an implementation of the interface. Create new classes along the way as needed (Customer, for instance), this makes you think about which properties are required.

```
[TestMethod()]
public void CreateCustomerRelationsTest()
{  
    var manager = new CustomerManager(MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICustomerHandler>());
    var result = manager.CreateCustomerRelations();
    Assert.AreEqual(1, result.HappyCustomers);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, result.UnhappyCustomers);
}
```

Writing this bogus test tells you what classes are needed, like a CustomerManager class which has a method CreateCustomerRelations and two properties. The method should refer to the GetCustomer method in the interface, using the instance of the mock that was being injected in the class constructor.

Do just enough to make the project build and let you run the test for the first time, which will fail as there's no logic in the method being tested. However, you are off on a great start with letting the test dictate which input your method should take, and what output it should receive and assert. Defining the test conditions first helps you in creating a good design. Soon you will have enough code written to ensure the test confirms your method is well designed and behaves the way you want it to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand it and in some cases I've come that far. And as I thought about it I probably had the wrong intention to program "from start to finish" - this is my "old I got used to" style of coding, but not the TDD way. One question though: What do I do when it comes to the point of Implementing `ICustomHandler`? No Unit tests here because it will be tested in Integration Tests?

Comment: Most likely, yes... since the implementation of that interface will be dependent on your database solution, which complicates isolation of that dependency from your code. It could contain just the bare bones needed to provide the "CustomerManager" class with data, and no logic at all, making it rather pointless to construct a unit test for it. An integration test would catch anything wrong with that method, I assume.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think I can go on from here.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what behaviour you are testing, and use this to drive a single higher level test. Then as you implement this functionality use TDD to drive out the behaviour you want in the classes you need to implement this functionality.

In your example I'd start with a simple no-op situation. (I'll write it in BDD langauge but you could similarly implement this in code)

```
Given there are no customers in the database
When I read customers and process the related data from the csv file
Then no data should be written to the database
```

This sort of test will allow you to get some of the basic functionality and interfaces in place without having to implement anything in your mocks (apart from maybe checking that you are not calling the code to do the final write)

Then I'd move on to a slightly wider example

```
Given there are some customers in the database
But none of these customers are in the CSV file
When I read customers and process the related data from the csv file
Then no data should be written to the database
```

And I would keep adding incrementally and adjusting the classes needed to do this, initially probably using mocks but eventually working up to using the real database interactions.

I'd be wary of writing a test for every class though. This can make your tests brittle and they can need changing every time you make a small refactoring like change. focus on the behaviour, not the implementation

your flow should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! I tried BDD with SpecFlow which seemed to be very promising but put that on hold until I have a better understanding of TDD and Unit Tests. Your way is definitly a way to go.